# Create multiple contact groups in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone help me in creating multiple contact groups like business, personal etc programatically. I need these groups and their contacts to be maintainable through an app.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a large task to ask someone to do for you. I can push you in a good direction though with a list of great video tutorials. I followed these tutorials when I first started Android development and I know for sure that your question would be covered in these tutorials.

Click [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A) to begin Android Development!

Answer (score 0):

Just very simple, collect the mail ID s of groups you want to post in one click. Go to your regular mail box, gmail or yahoo mail etc, prepare your post in a mail, copy paste all the IDs you have collected, provide a coma or semicolan between each as required by the mail client to separate each mail ID. Attach the files or Photos, send, over. You will find your post in all groups. If the groups dont have a mail ID, ask them to create one, its just 1 minut work and very simple.